# File_get_contents PHP Google Maps API - Not working

Tags: php, api, google-maps

Im using this code to get the Lat / Log of a postcode using GoogleMaps API

```
$geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NP265RE&sensor=false');
$outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
$latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
echo $latitudeFrom;
echo $longitudeFrom;
```

Im receiving this error from Google: { "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_", "results" : [], "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" }

I've created a google maps API Key

```
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=XXX"
```

But this does not solve me issue - What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding the api key to the like this `file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NP265RE&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY');`.

Comment: Does the Key have to be included on both the php file_get contents & the google maps script?

Comment: I think there's also some quotas on number of requests per IP. If your are on shared hosting, you won't be able to do requests like that (all other customers of your providers will "consume" the per IP quota). On shared hosting, websites share the same IP. For my own business websites, I can't do geolocation requests in PHP for those reasons, and I had to do them with javascript, client-side. There's still the per IP quota, but it's on the client computer, who has it's own IP.

Answer (score 4):

Yes because you are using 2 different APIs:

With `file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NP265RE&sensor=false');` you are using the [Geocoding web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

When you add `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=XXX">`on your html you are using the [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to render the map on your page.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple like that :)

Comment: Happy to help mate, please accept my answer to show apreciation. Thanks.